# Linearly Independence of sets.

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

I'm having trouble proving this statement even though it seems very intuitive.

Suppose the pairs of vectors $v_{1},v_{2};v_{1},v_{3};v_{2},v_{3}$ are linearly independent. Does it follow that $v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}$ must also be independent ? I know the statement is true  but I can't figure out how to start on the proof.

I know that $v_{1},v_{2}$ are independent if $$a_{1}v_{1} + a_{2}v_{2} = 0$$ where either $a_{1}=0$ and $a_{2}=0$. In other words there are only trivial solutions to the equation. And I want to show that from:

$$a_{1}v_{1} + a_{2}v_{2} = 0$$
$$a_{1}v_{1} + a_{3}v_{3} = 0$$
$$a_{2}v_{2} + a_{3}v_{3} = 0$$

where the linear equations above only holds for scalars $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}=0$. And this implies

$$a_{2}v_{2} +a_{2}v_{2}+ a_{3}v_{3} = 0$$

where the linear equation above only holds for scalars $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}=0$.

I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not true.

Let $v_1,v_2$ be any two linearly independent vectors, and let $v_3 = v_1 + v_2$.

Comment: That makes sense, I was thinking too hard about this.

Comment: Future suggestion: When you think something is true, but can't manage to prove it, put the proof attempt on hold, and try for a counterexample. If that fails, return to the proof attempt. Continue the process until something succeeds, either a proof or a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, can do sir.